# Granting access to a particular user Web API 2

Tags: sql-server, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I'm building a small CRM SPA application using Angular 2  (front-end) and Web API 2 as back-end with ASP.Net Identity and OWIN for token based authentication.
I've got ASPNetUsers, ASPNetRoles and I'm able to grant access to users based on roles but I don't understand how to grant access to a certain user. For example: 
a user logs-in with role 'Manager' and loads a page that makes a request for some resource that belongs to this Manager. This request reaches an API controller. How this controller method will know whether to grant access to this user or not? Is this user the owner of a ..say some Client. `/api/Client/1`

Is there a simple way of finding out (with EntityFramework) up the hierarchy of relations if a Client (or another resource) belongs to a current ASPNetUser or not?

This is how I plan the db relations will look like:
[image: database]

In the end the goal is to give user access to resources that he owns, and restrict other users to load them - sort of a personal account.

Comment: Perhaps this is a place to start(?): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: and if I use ASP.NET not ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Sheesh! Sorry. I should have read this more closely. You have all the right tags and everything! Can you update to Core? ;)

Comment: Short answer - no. More detailed - I thought of learning/using Core but I've chosen ASP.NET because I started learning it some time ago and I'd like to learn it deeper rather then knowing both quite shallow ... So I'm looking for a solution for ASP.NET.

Comment: Understandable! But, I think that learning Core is going offer more options long term. With Core, you can target Core, or the full framework. That isn’t the case with older ASP.NET Framework templates. I don’t think you will regret a deep dive into ASP.NET Core. I know I haven’t! Good luck no matter what you choose.